# Is it a bad practice to hide elements with CSS when you can't remove them with php?

Tags: php, css

Sometimes when I can't find the way of deactivating a function or any other elements with PHP, specially in PHP frameworks and PHP CMSs, I just do `display: none`, I wonder if this will cause me many problems in the future or is a necessary method?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the actual case and a general answer would be controversal and misleading. Do you have an real world example?

Comment: In a framework, you have complete control, so you shouldn't be generating things you don't need in the first place. In CMSes ... oh well that's a question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kinds of elements they are.

Possible problems that come to mind are:

- an `img` tag or some other tag pointing to an external resource: it will be loaded nevertheless
- the same applies to `iframe` tags - the embedded page will be loaded even when `display: none` is set
- Hidden elements' contents may still turn up in search engines
- If CSS is turned off in a client, the element will still be visible
- Automated clients parsing the DOM may not realize an element is hidden
- The element will still exist in the eyes of any JavaScript doing DOM manipulations

other than these special cases, it will probably not be a problem.

Comment: Interesting summary by Pekka.  I agree with svoop that an example to support the OP would be helpful (if only for my learning).